# JTable autoscroll to the bottom in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

I would like the JTable to autoscroll to the bottom whenever I add a new column and show the last 10 rows. However, I have the option of scrolling to anywhere I want (mouse listener?). Do you know how to do that? Here's the code I have so far. It builds a JTable and adds a new row for every mouse click on the JButton.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class sampleGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton incrementButton;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private int count;
    private JScrollPane scroll;


    public sampleGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("sample frame");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        incrementButton = new JButton("Increase the count!");

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("column 1");
        table = new JTable(model);
        frame.add(incrementButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table)
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        count = 0;

        incrementButton.addActionListener(this);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == incrementButton) {
            count++;
            model.addRow(new Object[] { count });
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sampleGUI gui = new sampleGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required to [change selection in JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), add code line

```
table.changeSelection(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, false, false);
```

to

```
public (synchronized) void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the JTable to autoscroll to the bottom whenever I add a new column

I assume you mean scroll to the bottom when you add a new row?

```
model.addRow(new Object[] { count });
table.scrollRectToVisible(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget add `JScrollPane` to the table :

```
//...
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
```

and don't forget

> import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

Comment: I added JScrollPane and modified some of my code. But how can you autoscroll to the bottom?

Comment: When you reach to the bottom of the frame and added more rows the scroll will appears.